# Replacing the ith element of a list with a slice object

Tags: python, list

This is a very simple question but I cannot find documentation anywhere for it. I would like to change the `i`th element of a list to a slice ("literal colon", like in `[:]`). Is there any way of doing this?

I have tried doing this:

```
indexlist = [0] * dim
indexlist[i] = :
```

This throws a syntax error but I think it gets the point across of what I would like to do.

Comment: Maybe `indexlist[i]= ':'`?

Comment: I had thought of this but I want it to be a literal colon not a string one.

Comment: And I dont understand the downvotes. If you think this is a bad question please tell me why.. if it is painfully obvious then please elaborate

Comment: Er, what? What is the difference between a "literal colon" and a string colon?

Comment: I think it's a bad question because of what @DanielRoseman said. An arbitrary symbol is not a valid variable value. Why not a string/char?

Comment: For example if you have a numpy array that you would like to parse array[0,:] would slice it but array[0,':'] would not slice.

Comment: So, if you had said in the beginning that this was a question about numpy slice syntax, people would not have downvoted.

Comment: Now I get what you're trying to do. You want to store slicing syntax in a variable. It doesn't really work like that though.

Comment: @keyser - Yes it does. e.g. the "literal colon" is `slice(None)`.

Comment: Read the Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: @JoeKington Well that's an object, not syntax, but fair enough :p My point was that OP shouldn't start trying to store code syntax in variables.

Comment: @keyser - Very true! However, it's a very common idiom to store slices, particularly in numpy, etc.

Comment: @JoeKington Agreed, it's a perfect solution for OP's problem.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman and keyser I edited the question to reflect a better understanding of the question. I stand by however that this is a good question. This is exactly what someone who is unfamiliar with what a slice object is would search for in google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By a "literal colon" you seem to mean a [slice object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice).

For example:

```
your_list[i] = slice(None)
```

To explain what's going on, slicing expressions are actually passed around as tuples of slice objects (or ints, etc).

`something[start:stop:step]` is equivalent to `something[slice(start, stop, step)]`.  Similarly, `something[:]` is equivalent to `something[slice(None)]`.

Slicing is implemented through an object's [`__getitem__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), so this is also equivalent to `something.__getitem__(slice(start, stop, step))`

---

Because you mention `numpy` in the comments, you might have a look at [`np.index_exp` or `np.s_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html).  It lets you quickly create tuples of slices from indexing, and allows you to see what happens.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

print np.s_[:, 1:5, ::-1, ...]
```

yields:

```
(slice(None, None, None), slice(1, 5, None), slice(None, None, -1), Ellipsis)
```

Which is a tuple of slice objects that you can store and then directly use to slice an object.  (e.g. `slices = np.s_[0, :, :]` and then `y = x[slices]`).

Comment: Thank you Joe. Exactly what I was looking for and very thorough! I knew there must be some way to do this.